# cover letter template which is stylistically similar to moderncv

Tags: moderncv, letters

the [Moderncv resumee template](http://www.latextemplates.com/template/moderncv-cv-and-cover-letter) is very well color coordinated. It isn't just plain black in comparison with the cover letter. Unfortunately, all cover letters I've found are just plain [black](http://www.latextemplates.com/cat/cover-letters) , which doesn't fit with the moderncv resumee. (because the moderncv template is colorful)

Basically, **I'm searching for an equal color-coordinated cover letter template like moderncv**. All questions on tex.stackexchange.com are using the plain business format I described above. Of course, i could extend the existing plain black color letters by adding some colors. But I want to know if such a template already exists.

**EDIT** For clarification: I saw the cover letter included in the moderncv package - but it looks still very business like and in my opinion provides a heavy contrast to the moderncv resumee itself.

Comment: Can you elaborate what makes the CV *"awesome"* and the cover letter *"business like"*?

Comment: You gotta tell us which parts you want to have coloured. Everything i can think of that makes it *less business* or less *black* are *99 Luftballons * in all colours of the rainbow drawn with TikZ all over the place.

Comment: You can do `\renewcommand*{\opening}[1]{\def\@opening{{\color{color1}#1}}}` (remember to handle the @ correctly).

Comment: I know i could create such a template on my own, but i was searching for an existing template/package (like moderncv itself is). So it seems i have to create my own template then. Thanks.

Comment: There is one answer that has color. I bet if you ask the guy who posted  it, he will see what he can do. But i am quite certain that he can't read minds so he needs to know what is expected.

Comment: Sidenote: You are using a template and want to change it, this is much more time consuming and confusing than doing stuff by hand.

Comment: @Johannes_B Hm. Is there then an alternative to include the compiled pdfs e.g. of the resumme into the cover letter?

Comment: Ich verstehe nur Bahnhof. You can merge pdfs (or include single pages of a pdf) using package `pdfpages`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[More colour, more joy.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Uctf_emj6jI)

[image: toogleyModerncvCoverColour]

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}

\moderncvstyle{casual}
\moderncvcolor{blue}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry}

\firstname{John}
\familyname{Smith}

\begin{document}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\opening}[1]{\def\@opening{{\color{color1}#1}}}
\renewcommand*{\closing}[1]{\def\@closing{{\color{color1}#1}}}
\makeatother
\renewcommand*{\addressfont}{\normalsize\mdseries\slshape\color{color2}}

\recipient{HR Department}{Corporation\\123 Pleasant Lane\\12345 City, State}
\date{\today}
\opening{Dear Sir or Madam,}
\closing{Sincerely yours,}
\enclosure[Attached]{curriculum vit\ae{}}

\makelettertitle

This is the letter text, no wombats can be found here. 

\makeletterclosing


\end{document}
```