# Creation of vertical blue line doesn't work

Tags: rules

I want to draw a a line like [that](http://www.latextemplates.com/template/vertical-line-title-page) in blue. In my code snippet, i use the variable `color1` which is given by [moderncv itself](https://github.com/xdanaux/moderncv/blob/master/moderncvcolorblue.sty#L20).

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}        

\usepackage{fontenc} 
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage{xcolor}

\moderncvstyle{casual}                        
\moderncvcolor{blue}                                
\usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry} 
\name{John}{Doe}

\renewcommand*{\rule}[2]{\def\@rule{\color{color1}{#1}{#2}}}


\begin{document} 
\makecvtitle 
\hbox{
        \hspace*{0.2\textwidth}
        \rule{5pt}{\textwidth}
        \hspace*{0.05\textwidth} 
} 

\end{document}
```

why does that not work here? When compiling that with `latexmk -xelatex $file` i just get a plain white site with just the name John Doe on it.

Comment: Why do you redefine \rule instead of using `\textcolor{color1}{\rule{5pt}{\textwidth}}`? (And where did you get this curious redefinition?)

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Ah, I didn't knew this was that simple. Thanks. Would you mind to put you comment into an answer so i can mark it solved?

Comment: But out of curiosity - I would still like to know what was the problem with that redefinition, although my problem is basically solved.

Comment: You are defining \rule to define another command. So why should it print anything? (Beside the fact that you don't know about \makeatletter).

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Well, i tried to adapt http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/299974/76157 for my needs. And this answer used the redefinition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer you mention in comments indeed has

```
\renewcommand*{\opening}[1]{\def\@opening{{\color{color1}#1}}}
```

but it's a completely different situation. The definition of `\opening` by `moderncv` is

```
\newcommand*{\opening}[1]{\def\@opening{#1}}
```

which means that the argument to `\opening` is saved in `\@opening` for later usage. The redefinition instead saves the argument along with the desired color setting.

The definition of `\rule` is completely different:

```
% latex.ltx, line 4984:
\DeclareRobustCommand\rule{\@ifnextchar[\@rule{\@rule[\z@]}}%
```

Imagine `\DeclareRobustCommand` like `\newcommand`. The purpose of the definition is to check whether `[` follows and to pass control to the internal command `\@rule`. There's a fundamental difference between the two cases: `\@opening` is just a container, `\@rule` is a macro with arguments which is in charge of producing the rule.

You are instead trying to redefine `\@rule` and this is unfortunately wrong.

What you should do is to define a new command, because `\rule` might get used in other situations (perhaps internally, without you knowing). Do

```
\newcommand{\colorrule}[3][0pt]{\textcolor{color1}{\rule[#1]{#2}{#3}}}
```

and use `\colorrule` where you need a colored rule.

Answer (score 0):

This works I think.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}        
\usepackage{fontenc} 
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage{xcolor}
\moderncvstyle{casual}                        
\moderncvcolor{blue}                                
\usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry} 
\name{John}{Doe}

\begin{document} 

\parbox[b]{0.75\textwidth}{%
\hbox{\hspace*{0.2\textwidth}
\color{blue}
\rule{1pt}{\textheight} 
\hspace*{0.05\textwidth}}}  
\vskip-9in  
\vtop{\makecvtitle \hspace{2in}Hello World}

\end{document}
```